# How to detect invalid user input in ARM Assembly

Tags: assembly, arm

How do I detect when a user enters an invalid inpuut like "1B0", then the program would say (branch `invalid`) "invalid string, re-enter value". I assume you use `cmp` to compare the user's input with something else, but I don't know what I'm comparing that input to. Any help is much appreciated.

```
num1Enter:

@ OUTPUT INSTRUCTION TO CONSOLE
ldr r0, =enterNum1  @ Load address of r0 into enterNum1
bl putstring        @ Display the string to the terminal

@ READ-IN NUM1 DATA
ldr r0, =szNum1 @ Load address of r0 into szNum1
mov r1, #512    @ Load address of r1 into 512 bytes
bl getstring    @ Read a string of characters terminated by a null

@ CONVERT NUM1 TO INT
ldr r0, =szNum1 @ Load address of r0 into szNum1
bl ascint32     @ Converts a string of characters to an equivalent 4-byte (word) value.
ldr r1, =iNum1  @ Load address of r1 into iNum1
str r0, [r1]    @ Store r0 into address of r1

ldr r0, =iNum1  @ Load address of r0 into iNum1
ldr r1, [r0]    @ Load address of r0 into szNum1

b invalid

invalid:

ldr r0, =invalidMsg
bl putstring

@ NEWLINE
ldr r0, =cCr
bl putch

b num1Enter // return to num1Enter
```

Comment: If your `ascint32` has some sort of error return, check that. Otherwise verify each character is in the range `'0'..'9'`. Consult an [ascii table](http://www.asciitable.com)

Comment: `ascint32` converts ascii to integer. that works fine.

Comment: Oh I assume it does. What I meant if it has a way to indicate invalid input itself.

Comment: I think getString can help with validating the user input. I just need to know how to do it by using `cmp` I saw another question that involved using `cmp` to validate input.

Comment: I'd suggest modifying `ascint32` to return an error status in flags, like setting or clearing the `C` flag to indicate error or not.  It already has to look at each character one at a time.

Comment: Are you refering to `ls`?